# weirdness of own linear regression implementation

Tags: regression, python

I decided to implement linear regression by myself in python. I compared it against scikit-learn. For that I used scikit-learn diabetes dataset (10-dimensional)

Code for dataset:

```
m = diabetes['data'].shape[0] # m is number of data points 
X, Y = np.c_[np.ones(m), diabetes['data']], diabetes['target']
Y = Y.reshape((Y.shape[0], 1))
X_train = X[:-20]
X_test = X[-20:]
Y_train = Y[:-20]
Y_test = Y[-20:]
```

So I augmented the dataset with a column of ones so my model has now 11 coefficients (because it is the standard to do so, am I right?).

Code of my implementation:

```
import numpy as np
class LinearRegressionModel:

    def __init__(self, dim):
        self.iters = 30000
        self.alpha = 1
        self.learning_rate = 0.01
        self.coef_ = np.random.random((dim,1)) #TODO: randomly initialize coefficients

    def coef(self):
        return self.coef_

    def predict(self, x):
        return np.dot(x, self.coef_)

    def computeCostFunction(self, X_training_data, Y_training_data):
        m = X_training_data.shape[0]
        diff = np.dot(X_training_data, self.coef_) - Y_training_data
        return np.sum(diff ** 2) / (2 * m)

    def gradientDescent(self, X_training_data, Y_training_data):
        m = X_training_data.shape[0]        
        for _ in range(self.iters):
            diff = np.dot(X_training_data, self.coef_) - Y_training_data
            self.coef_ = self.coef_ - (self.alpha / m) * np.dot(X_training_data.T, diff)

    def fit(self, X_training_data, Y_training_data):
            # m - number of data points
            m = X_training_data.shape[0]
            if m != Y_training_data.shape[0]:
                raise ValueError('y_train_data and x_train_data data size - number of data points - mismatch')
            else:
                self.gradientDescent(X_training_data, Y_training_data)
```

Code for scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
clf.coef_
```

What I found is that the both models learn same coefficients but not the first one (the one that corresponds to column vector of ones)

Coefficients for scikit-learn:

```
[[  0.00000000e+00   3.03499549e-01  -2.37639315e+02   5.10530605e+02
    3.27736980e+02  -8.14131709e+02   4.92814588e+02   1.02848452e+02
    1.84606489e+02   7.43519617e+02   7.60951722e+01]]
```

My coefficients:

```
    [[  1.52764197e+02,   3.13736959e-01,  -2.37629889e+02, 5.10557036e+02, 
 3.27729240e+02,  -8.12127495e+02,      4.91230215e+02,   1.01941305e+02, 
  1.84335882e+02,   7.42771265e+02,   7.61048357e+01]]
```

Comment: Have a look at our [help/on-topic] to see what's on-topic on our site - this seems to be a "debug my code" question rather than one that focuses on an underlying statistical issue, so I'm not sure it's a good fit here.

Comment: Why are you using gradient descent to solve a problem with an algebraic solution?

Comment: General discussions about algorithms for instance are on-topic here so I wonder if it would be possible for you to edit this question to bring it more within the scope of our site. Also, I can't help but have a few alarm bells about the `0.00000000e+00` in the scikit-learn coefficients. I'm pretty sure that's telling you something.

Comment: @Sycorax he's jus learning. Actual implementation in python uses SVD decomposition,

Answer (score 6):

scikit-learn by default adds an intercept to the model – `fit_intercept` is [true by default](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression). So, when you additionally add a column of all ones, putting weight on `intercept_` is equivalent to putting weight on `coef_[0]`; it's only the sum of the two that affects the model. So it's implementation-dependent how the weight gets split up. It so happens that the way scikit-learn solves it, all the weight goes into `intercept_` here. If you want identical results, use `LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False)` or don't add the column of all ones.